# Ruby on Rails 3 undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes, image-upload

I have been working on this for a couple of days, searching here and there got me somehow close to my objective.

I am trying to have multiple images upload in my application.

Movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :notes, :link, :screenshots_attributes
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  has_many :screenshots
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :screenshots, allow_destroy: true
  belongs_to :cast
end
```

Screentshot.rb

```
class Screenshot < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :movie_id
  belongs_to :movie
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Movie_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(params[:movie])
    @cast = Cast.find(params[:cast_id])
    if @release.save
      redirect_to cast_movie_path(params[:cast_id], @movie), notice: "#{t 'movie.created'}"
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end
```

_form.html.rb (movie)

```
  <%= form_for [@cast, @movie], :id => 'fileupload' do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :movie %></div><%= t 'movie.title' %><br />

    <%= f.fields_for :screenshots do |s| %>
      <%= s.file_field :image, multiple: true %><%= t 'movie.screenshots' %><br />
    <% end %>

    <%= f.text_area :notes %></div><%= t 'movie.notes' %></div><br />

    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "#{ t 'general.submit'}", :class => "btn"%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

when I submit the form, only ONE image gets uploaded although when I "raise params.to_yaml" (for debugging purposes), I get NoMethodError

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

and Request parameters http://pastebin.com/4iZvtnED

Comment: Where is `@cast` defined?

Comment: Sorry, in create action. I removed it by mistake with some unnecessary fields. but yea, @cast is definitely needed here

Comment: I have it in "new" and "edit" actions btw

Comment: Where is the undefined method for nil:NilClass being raised (i.e which line)?

Comment: whenever I submit the form whether create or update and put "raise params.to_yaml". It is raised in this line. even with "raise params[:movie].to_yaml" I get the same error. However, params[:movie][:title].to_s return the title without any problems. The request params I posted shows that all the pics get submitted, but only ONE gets uploaded :S